# Create CGContext from array of CGPoints

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgcontext

I have an `NSArray` of `CGPoint`s which I have extracted from an `UIImage`. These points are segmented from an irregular closed area in the image, i.e. as in image segmentation. As shown inside the red rectangle in this image:

[image]

How can I create a `CGContext` from these points only so that when I draw on the image, only these points are effected?

Comment: You want to create a mask and use `CGContextClipToMask` I think.  The mask is a grey image where black values are unchanged and white are set to transparent when drawing -- so only the areas with black pixels get drawn on -- (I think, read the docs https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1456497-cgcontextcliptomask)

Comment: Maybe you want to create a CGPath from those points and clip using that path?

Comment: @LouFranco Yea, I have tried this and it was useful. I have created image mask from the original image and marked the clipping pixels with white color whereas the others are black, then clip the context to this image mask and it works perfectly. Please add this as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @Sulthan i have tried this and it works semi-correct since the points are not ordered and the resulting path is not correctly created.

Comment: @AmaniElsaed If your points are not ordered into a shape, there is basically nothing you can do.

Comment: @AmaniElsaed Glad that worked -- I put in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a mask and use `CGContextClipToMask`. The mask is a grey image where black values are unchanged and white are set to transparent when drawing -- so only the areas with black pixels get drawn on.

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1456497-cgcontextcliptomask